# Resolving ambiguous references

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, ambiguous

I have code spread across a number of files using std::set. Each of these files also have an using directive `using std::set;`. I am now introducing dependency on a 3rd party library which has defined a const named `set`. Now the compiler fails giving an ambiguous reference error between the `std::set` and the `set` variable defined in the 3rd party library. I could fix the issue by explicitly specifying the scope (`std::set`) wherever I use this type. But doing this across a large number of files is very painful. I have 2 questions:

1. Shouldn't `using std::set` take care of this error?
2. Is there any way of resolving this ambiguity other than explicitly scoping the type for each instance of the type in every file across the project?

Comment: _"Shouldn't `using std::set`;'take care of this error?"_ I'd suspect it's causing it actually.

Comment: Is the 3rd party library not using namespaces?

Comment: It does actually. It is a variable defined in boost::xpressive::detail namespace

Comment: Then it should be scoped to that namespace, unless you also have `using boost::xpressive::detail` in your code.

Comment: Please show actual code. Then we can say if you should be using `using`, or not.

Comment: This is why you should've just written `std::set` in the first place.

Comment: Just do a search-and-replace `set<` to `std::set<` and get rid of the `using` directives?

Comment: @zenith If this is a project with (tens of) thousands of lines of code, where `using std::set` was common practice, changing that in many, many places could be quite painful and touch a lot of things in a lot of places. It also requires you to get every developer on the project on board with the new coding style. Neither are necessarily trivial things.

Comment: @aruisdante thanks for pointing out that I might have an unnecesary `using boost::xpressive::detail` somewhere. Removing that fixed the issue.